# Is it possible to combine comprehension and key-value listing in dictionary definition?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to define a dictionary wherein some key-value pairs can be specified using comprehension (because these pairs are formulaic), while others need to be specified explicitly. Due to a coding guideline restriction, the dictionary definition needs to be a single assignment statement. Therefore, no multiple assignments to compose the dictionary. Is it possible to combine explicit key-value specification along with comprehension to define the dictionary?

Minimal example:

```py
d = {
    '0': 0x1,
    '0'*r + 'X': 0x100 + r for r in range(2), # r is much larger in real-world application
    'Y': 0xA
}
```

Expected output:

```
>>> d
    {'0': 1, 'X' = 256, '0X' = 257, 'Y' = 10}
```

Error:

```py
d = {
    '0': 0x1,
    '0'*r + 'X': 0x100 + r for r in range(2),
    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge two or more dictionaries in one expression by using the dictionary unpacking syntax `**` ([PEP 448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/)), see: [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python)

```
d = {'0': 0x1, **inner, 'Y': 0xA}
```

In this case, the inner dictionary is created by a dictionary comprehension:

```
{'0'*r + 'X': 0x100 + r for r in range(2)}
```

So the resulting expression is:

```
d = {
    '0': 0x1,
    **{'0'*r + 'X': 0x100 + r for r in range(2)},
    'Y': 0xA
}
```